# How to import linked images and make them featured -> automagically

Tags: post-thumbnails, feed

I am using FeedWordPress to syndicate articles from RSS feeds.
The plugin does a *beautiful job* of bringing in the content, preserving original formatting, and assigning metadata to the right places. Images are displayed by linking to source images.
What I want to do:

- automatically import all images from syndicated posts, and add them to the media library.

  - import to media library should handle image processing to create thumbnails, etc.
- automatically assign image #1 as the featured image, to be used in widgets.

The plugin doesn't seem to support these features.
Can you suggest another plugin, or configurations that can help to support these features?

Comment: Hey ted, plugin recommendations are off-topic. Code suggestions are too broad if you don't tell us what you've done so far and where exactly you are stuck. Apart from that this seems like a copyright-sensitive request and we'd need more information on that as well. Please update your question accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Searching the plugin support forum, I have found this plugin [Add Linked Images To Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/). This plugin appears to handle the first half of my problem: auto-importing images to media library. No support for auto-feature-izing the first image.